# Nose main() with no arguments produces odd behavior

Tags: python, flask, nose, flask-script, flask-testing

I have a Flask app and I am using Flask-Script and Flask-Testing. Basically I have a `manage.py` file that looks like this:

```
from flask.ext.script import Manager
from app import app, db

manager = Manager(app)

@manager.command
def test():
    import nose
    nose.main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

My app tree looks like:

```
app/
tests/
    __init__.py
    test_one.py
manage.py
```

`__init__.py` holds only some things that make Flask-SQLAlchemy things work in tests and `test_one.py` contains just an empty test function.

The odd things is: When I run `python manage.py test`, it starts executing some wierd tests (I believe tests from Python itself).
If I change `nose.main()` to `nose.main(argv=[''])`, my test is properly discovered and everything goes well.

What's wrong with using the plain `nose.main()`?

Comment: Can you show some output of the `nose.main()` command (which tests are getting run) ? Thing is nose will read `sys.argv` if `argv` is `None`, i think when you run it like `python manage.py test` that will get passed to to `sys.argv`, not sure though, your output will help.

Comment: Yes, this was the problem. `nose.main()` was passed `sys.argv` and it was searching for some weird tests. You can submit your answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nose will read `sys.argv` if `argv` is `None`, i think when you run it like `python manage.py test` that will get passed to `sys.argv`.